# If value doesn't exist in column create new row

Tags: excel, vba

I have a table with 2 columns: A and B. I would like to search in column A if a value in column B exists. If it doesn't exist, I want to add this value in the last row of column A and if it exist, I don't want to do anything. I want this to happen for every value in column B until its end. For example, if there are 3 values in column B that don't exist in column A, I want them to be added as 3 new rows at the end of column A.

Here's an example:

Before:

[image: screenshot 1]

After:

[image: screenshot 2]

Any ideas?
Thanks

Comment: Is it a table or just a sheet?

Comment: It's a table with just 2 columns. Thanks!

Comment: So that's a ListObject on a Sheet. Do you have any existing code so that we can modify that?

Comment: Unfortunately not. I'm very new to this and I'm struggling to write a code for this particular case. Let me know if you want me to share any pictures or anything that would help.

Comment: I uploaded 2 screenshots. 1-> Before solution and 2->expected outcome after solution

Comment: From what I see, this is not a table, just two columns A & B of the Excel Sheet, right?

Comment: Yes, I'm sorry. I misunderstood your first question.

Comment: Ok, try the answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your pictures, I assume this is just a sheet, so this code should work for you:

```vb
Sub Macro1()

Dim rngA As Range, rngB As Range, MySel As Range, LastRow As Long, ws As Worksheet
Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1)

With ws
    LastRow = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    Set rngA = .Range("A1:A" & LastRow)
    Set rngB = .Range("B1", .Range("B" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
End With

For Each cell In rngB
    If IsError(Application.Match(cell.Value, rngA, 0)) Then
        If MySel Is Nothing Then
            Set MySel = cell
        Else
            Set MySel = Union(MySel, cell)
        End If
    End If
Next cell

If Not MySel Is Nothing Then MySel.Copy Destination:=ws.Range("A" & LastRow + 1)
End Sub
```